# How to select the inside of jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some HTML in a jQuery object:

```
var $div = $(`
  <div class="myDiv">
    <p class="name"></p>
    <p class="data"></p>
  </div>`);
```

I want to change the content of the `<p>` elements, so I tried like this but in vain:

```
// Attempt #1
$div.".name".html("name here");

// Attempt #2
$div."> P".html("name here");
```

How can I use a selector to get the inside of jQuery variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you would do when the elements are in the DOM, you need to use `find()` to retrieve elements within the object. Try this:

```js
var $div = $(`<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="data"></p>
</div>`);

$div.find('p').text('name here');
$div.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! it's big help. I think it is from jquery though , it is from DOM.